# CAML: Not in Group

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml

Building a CAML query in SP. Want to result item where current user not in group that is in the AssignedTo field.

Tried wit Neq, NotIncluded:

```
<View>
  <Query>
    <Where>
      <Neq>
        <Membership Type="CurrentUserGroups"><FieldRef Name="AssignedTo"/></Membership>
      </Neq>
    </Where>
  </Query>
</View>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Does my suggestion help you?

Comment: no, maybe for scripting but I need it in a listview, sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot use 'Ne' with 'Membership' as the parent tag supported for `<Membership>` are

- And
- Or
- Where

[For reference you can refer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/membership-element-query)

Comment: ok good to know, any more ideas?

Comment: are comfortable with rest but there is also direct endpoint but can share script

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSOM to display the specific items as you want. Use [SPWeb.CurrentUser.Groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.currentuser.aspx) to get the collection of groups of which the user is a member. And use CAML query  to filter on items which were not assigned to current user and current user’s groups.

Demo:

Note: Change "task01" to your list name.

```
<div id="displayDiv"></div>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
    //This example gets the items in the cl_Latest list that created by user or created by user group's memberships.   
    //This variable will hold the list items collection  
    var returnedItems = null;
    var groups = null;  
    var groupId="";
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getGroups);
    function getGroups(){
        //Get the current context   
        var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
        var oWeb = context.get_web();
        //Get current user
        var currentUser = oWeb.get_currentUser();
        //Gets the collection of groups of which the user is a member
        groups = currentUser.get_groups();
        context.load(groups);
        context.executeQueryAsync(loopGroups, onFailedCallback);
    }
function loopGroups(){
        if (groups !== null){
            var groupEnumerator = groups.getEnumerator();
            var queryString1 = "<View><Query><Where>";
            var queryString2 = "";
            while (groupEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var group = groupEnumerator.get_current();
                var gName = group.get_title();
                queryString2 += "<Neq><FieldRef Name= 'AssignedTo'/><Value Type='Text'>"+gName+"</Value></Neq></And>"
                queryString1 += "<And>"
                console.log("name: "+gName);
            } 
            console.log(queryString1);
            var queryString3 = queryString1 + "<Neq><FieldRef Name= 'AssignedTo'/><Value Type='Integer'><UserID Type='Integer'/></Value></Neq>"+queryString2;
            queryString3 += "</Where></Query></View>";
            console.log(queryString3);
            queryListItems(queryString3);
}
    }
function queryListItems(queryString) { 
        //console.log("run group id:"+groupId);
        var context2 = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();  
        //Get the Announcements list. Alter this code to match the name of your list  
        var list = context2.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('task01');       
        //Create a new CAML query  
        var caml = new SP.CamlQuery();  
        //Create the CAML that will return   
        caml.set_viewXml(queryString);  
        //Specify the query and load the list oject  
        returnedItems = list.getItems(caml);  
        context2.load(returnedItems);  
        //Run the query asynchronously, passing the functions to call when a response arrives  
        context2.executeQueryAsync(onSucceededCallback, onFailedCallback);  
    }  
//This function fires when the query completes successfully  
    function onSucceededCallback(sender, args) { 
        console.log("Display items for group:"+groupId);    
        //Get an enumerator for the items in the list  
        var enumerator = returnedItems.getEnumerator();  
        //Formulate HTML from the list items  
        var markup = '';  
        //Loop through all the returned items  
        while (enumerator.moveNext()) {  
            var listItem = enumerator.get_current();  
            markup += 'Item Title: ' + listItem.get_item('Title') + '<br>';  
            markup += 'Item ID: ' + listItem.get_id() + '<br>'; 
            console.log(listItem.get_item('AssignedTo')); 
            if (listItem.get_item('AssignedTo') == null){
                        markup += 'Assigned To:  none <br>';
            }else{
                        var users="";
                        for(var i = 0;i < listItem.get_item('AssignedTo').length;i++) {
                                   users += listItem.get_item('AssignedTo')[i].get_lookupValue() +"; "; 
                        }
                        markup += 'Assigned To: ' + users + '<br>';
            }            
            markup += 'Create By: ' + listItem.get_item('Author').get_lookupValue() + '<br><br>'; 
        }  
        //Display the formulated HTML in the displayDiv element  
        displayDiv.innerHTML += markup;  
    }  
    //This function fires when the query fails  
    function onFailedCallback(sender, args) {  
        console.log("Display items for group:"+groupId);
        //Formulate HTML to display details of the error  
        var markup = '<p>The request failed: <br>';  
        markup += 'Message: ' + args.get_message() + '<br>';  
        //Display the details  
        displayDiv.innerHTML += markup;  
    }  
</script>
```

Add the following code into a page. It will only display the items which were not assigned to the current user and current user’s groups from the specific list.